# How do i change React Google Charts background color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to change the background color of the charts to match my body background color.

I have tried to do the two following backgroundColor styles below but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how i can get around this?

```
<Chart
                height={'300px'}
                width={'370px'}
                chartType='Bar'
                loader={<div>Loading Chart..</div>}
                data={[
                  ['', 'UPLIFT'],
                  ...topSpend.map(d => [d.PRODUCT, d.UPLIFT]),
                ]}
                options={{
                  chart: {
                    title: 'Spend Uplift',
             -----> backgroundColor: 'red'
                  },
                  colors: ['#FB7A21']
                }}
              />

<Chart
                height={'300px'}
                width={'370px'}
                chartType='Bar'
                loader={<div>Loading Chart..</div>}
                data={[
                  ['', 'UPLIFT'],
                  ...topSpend.map(d => [d.PRODUCT, d.UPLIFT]),
                ]}
                options={{
                  chart: {
                    title: 'Spend Uplift',
                  },
                  colors: ['#FB7A21'],
           -----> backgroundColor: 'red'
                }}
              />
```

Comment: According to the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options) you should be able to use as is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `chartType` as `BarChart`. For some reason, `Bar` seems to cause issues. In case you want the chart bars to be vertical, change it to `ColumnChart`.

You can see the working fiddle [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rakannimerreact-google-charts-bar-chart-293mu)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've started using ColumnChart now.

Answer (score 1):

`'Bar'` is considered a *Material* chart.

vs. `'BarChart'`, which is a *Classic* chart.

with *Material* charts, an options conversion method needs to be used...

```
google.charts.Bar.convertOptions
```

which means you would need to access the `google.charts` namespace.

```
options={google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
  chart: {
    title: 'Spend Uplift',
  },
  colors: ['#FB7A21'],
  backgroundColor: 'red'
})}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I couldn't access google.charts namespace so I instead used ColumnChart and everything is working.