# React google charts axis and text color not changing

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-google-charts

I am using [react-google-charts](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-https-6z4jc3?file=%2FApp.tsx%3A48%2C1) library in my project to display a bar graph for some data.

The issue I am facing is that i am unable to change my x&y axis line color and the text color too for those axis respectively and also not able to change background color for the entire chart. Here is my code below

```
import React from "react";

import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

const BarChart = () => {
  const data = [
    ["Year", "Sales"],
    ["2014", 1000],
    ["2015", 1170],
    ["2016", 660],
    ["2017", 1030],
  ];

  const options = {
    chart: {
        title: "Company Performance",
        subtitle: "Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017",
    },
    colors: ["#895d85"], //this is bar color, which works fine
    hAxis: {
      title: "Total Population",
      minValue: 0,
      textStyle: { color: "blue" }, //this doesnt work
      gridlines: {
        color: "#895d85", //this doesnt work
      },
      baselineColor: "#895d85", //this doesnt work
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: "City",
      textStyle: {
        color: "green", //this doesnt work
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="Bar"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      data={data}
      options={options}
      //tried applying backgroundcolor and that doesnt work too
    />
  );
};

export default BarChart;



  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts
```

Tried applying the styles after going through some sourced but failing as you can see mentioned in the inline commnets. I also created a codesandbox repo for it someone wants to look at it [codesandbox repo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-https-6z4jc3?file=%2FApp.tsx%3A48%2C1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560847/7545496 , changing the chartType from `Bar` to `BarChart` should do the trick.

Unfortunately, there is no explanation but I have verified in the codesandbox that it seems to work.